# JSON.stringify(undefined) is not a string

Tags: javascript, json

[image: JSON undefined errors]

`JSON.stringify(null)` returns the string `null`.

`JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns the value `undefined`. Shouldn't it return the *string* `undefined`?

Parsing the value `undefined` or the string `undefined` gives a `SyntaxError`.

Could someone explain why JSON chokes on `undefined` and how to get around it when stringifying / parsing values?

Comment: To get around it perhaps try `JSON.stringify( myvar ? myvar : "*ERROR*" )`

Comment: or `JSON.stringify( myvar || "*ERROR*" )`

Comment: "*Shouldn't it return the string undefined?*" No. `undefined` isn't [recognized by JSON](http://json.org/). `JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar', baz: undefined }) === '{"foo":"bar"}'`. `undefined` is also how you skip values [with the `replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: `JSON.stringify(undefined)` it the same as calling `JSON.stringify()` (i.e. without any arguments).

Comment: The types from "/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts" do not indicate this possibility...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`undefined` is not valid JSON, so the function is working properly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Answer (score 3):

```
if(JSON.stringify(input) === undefined) {
    // error handle
}
```

or

```
if(input === undefined) {
    // error handle
}
else {
    JSON.stringify(input);
}
```

Sorry.  Life is hard sometimes.  This is pretty much what you have to do.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that `null` is caused by a variable that doesn't have a value, so when converted to JSON it gives you JSON that doesn't have a value, undefined means it doesn't exist at all, so you can't create a JSON object of something that doesn't exist.  Just check

```
 if(typeof myvar === 'undefined')
```

before you run it and handle the error gracefully in the code.
Generally try to avoid `undefined` in your JS they can to weird things all over the place, and are NOT the same as `null` and are usually handled differently.

Comment: Javascript is a bit weird. Properties can exist and still be undefined: `window.x = undefined; console.log(window.x); console.log(x in window); // undefined, true`

Comment: true, similaraly undefined can be defined `undefined = "hello"`.  Got to love JavaScript

Comment: As of the most recent versions of ECMAScript `undefined` is not writable, so that would leave the value of `undefined` unchanged, but it's true that in old versions that would overwrite the value of `undefined`.